# Is there any secure method to have recoverable passwords?

Tags: passwords, algorithm

I have a local application that normally authenticates against a remote Active Directory server. If the local host loses network connectivity, a special local account becomes available for login. Currently, that account has a standard password that our technicians know.

In the event that our technician is unavailable, the enduser would like to allow their technicians to log in using that account. However, the enduser does not want their techs to log in without calling our help desk for the password, after which the password should be changed.

Furthermore, each of the hundreds of sites should have a different password.

The proposal at the moment is to have a service that runs on the local host and changes the password every day. Our help desk will have an identical tool that will tell them what the password of the day is. The password would be generated by seeding a random number generator with the date and xor-ing it with the site name.

If anyone has the source code or can analyze the binary, I assume they would be able to derive the password, no matter the algorithm used, but I'm a security/crypto novice.

Is there a methodology or algorithm, any way to do this that is secure?

This is a deployed system, so significant architecture changes are unlikely to be approved. As things stand at the moment, no changes to the app will be approved.

Comment: I'm confused about the lines of authority and ownership here. Who owns the system? It's the owner who should have ultimate access to the system.

Comment: @schroeder The owner (enduser) doesn't want their techs to access the local hosts in this situation without callling us first. I don't know why.

Comment: Alternately, you can solve this without any technology change and without you getting involved: *get them to manage their own service passwords!!* I'm really not sure why your dev team *and* the customer service team is getting involved to manage things for your customers.

Comment: @schroeder Having them deal with it was my first proposal.

Comment: You do not want the responsibility to know all your customer's service passwords, then give them out, and then change them for all your customers. If they are the owners, they need to manage their own service accounts. You take on a lot of liability if you store them.

Comment: @schroeder I couldn't agree more.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are lots of processes you could use to get all clever with managing the passwords for your customers.

***And you do not want to do any of them!***

The end result is that you, as the developers and vendor, will know the admin service accounts for your customers. That means that you take on the responsibility and liability to manage them securely. In addition, if anything happens to the customer's system/data, they can blame you because you have access to the admin account.

You want your customers to keep the passwords themselves and manage access to them. Just like every other service password they use. Tell them to use a password manager controlled by an authorised party and when needed, the authorised party can disclose the relevant credentials.

You do not want the responsibility.

Else, you get a password manager yourself, and start the data entry process to enter in all those passwords (I hope you don't have typos) and then open up the password manager to your customer service team so that they can tell people over the phone (oh yeah, have an ID verification process). There are password managers that can be shared with a team so that a customer service manager can release just the one customer's details to the relevant CS rep.

Comment: We wouldn't have to enter passwords, they will be generated automatically and set by a daemon. We need to be able to reproduce that password so we can give it to the enduser's tech.

Comment: Then you are looking at recreating a secure password manager. Generating the password is only one tiny piece to the puzzle. A puzzle you don't really want to solve ...